# Can anyone help me on my code? I have write my problem on body part of the section?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Can anyone help me on my code?
In my code isFirstTimeSearch and isSearchBool state are not updated inside getData() after handleSubmitBtn is click? But when, i m trying this stuff using let variable and try to console inside getData(), then it's working.

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, ScrollView, Keyboard, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const SearchScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [isSearchBool, setSearchBool] = useState(false);
    const [isFirstTimeSearch, setFirstTimeSearch] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmitBtn = () => {
        setSearchBool(true);
        setFirstTimeSearch(true);
        getData();
    }

    const getData = async () => {
        if (!loading && !isListEnd) {
            console.log('getData');
            setLoading(true);
            const BASE_URL = "https://api.unsplash.com"
            console.log(`set search boolean to: ${isSearchBool}`);
            console.log(`set First search boolean to: ${isFirstTimeSearch}`);
            if(isSearchBool && isFirstTimeSearch){
                console.log("Set Page Number to 1");
                setPage(1);
            } 
            console.log(page);
            
        }
    };


    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                <TextInput
          onSubmitEditing={handleSubmitBtn}
                    onChangeText={setSearchText}
                    value={searchText}
                    placeholder="Search Photos, collections"
                    onFocus={() => setClicked(true)}
                />
        </View>
    )}

export default SearchScreen;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because of useState hook's asynchronous behaviour, you can read more on this [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#troubleshooting)

To resolve this issue you can add some delay before calling the getData method like this

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  getData();
}, 200); //here 200 value is in milliseconds feel free to change
```

Alternatively you can pass the `isSearchBool` and `isFirstTimeSearch` as a parameter to the getData() method.

Hope this helps.